# Quick Build commands in WinEdt

Tags: texmaker, automation, winedt

I recently switched from TeXMaker to WinEdt.

In TeXMaker I was used to customize my 'Quick Build' command in the 'Configure TeXMaker' dialog.

In that dialog I was able to choose, for example:

> LaTeX + dvips + ps2pdf + View PDF

or to customize it to my needs inserting, through the wizard:

> PdfLaTeX + Bibtex + Makeindex + PdfLaTeX + PdfLaTeX + Pdf Viewer

Does anyone knows a way to do the same in WinEdt?

Comment: This kind of thing is a good reason to consider using `arara`- see pg 36 of the manual for details about `winedt`

Comment: @cmhughes look at the bottom of my answer... BTW, the add-on I mentioned is not contemplated in `arara` manual. Much better than dealing manually with WinEdt scripts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In WinEdt, the command 'PDFTeXify' is some sort of 'Quick Build' command (also exists 'TeXify' for the DVI cycle).

It runs `pdflatex` and compile bibliographies, indexes and glossaries automatically to get a fully compiled document, that is something similar to:

> pdfLaTeX + BibTeX + MakeIndex + MakeGlossaries + pdfLaTeX + View PDF

To customize it, you have to open the 'Execution Modes' interface ('Options' menu) and go the the 'TeX Options' page.

[image]

To obtain the equivalent of

> LaTeX + dvips + ps2pdf + View PDF

you just have to check 'dvi -> ps -> pdf' in 'PDFTeXify Method'. Note that bibliographies, indexes and glossaries get compiled (when needed) even if you opt for this choice.

You can press the 'Help' button in that dialog to know more about the available choices.

For example, choosing 'Default' in 'PDFTeXify Method' and 'xelatex.exe' in 'Default PDFTeXify Engine' you get something like

> XeLaTeX + BibTeX + MakeIndex + MakeGlossaries + XeLaTeX + View PDF

If you want to further customize the execution of the various accessories (e.g. change `bibtex` to `biber`) you have to go to the page 'Console Application'

[image]

I suggest you to press the 'Help' button here to know how to set the lots of choices you have.

---

If you want to add capabilities of compiling nomenclatures or inline Asymptote graphics to the 'PDFTeXify' command, have a look at these add-ons: [Nomenclature](http://www.winedt.org/config/menus/Nomenclature.html) and [Asymptote](http://www.winedt.org/config/menus/Asymptote.html).

Moreover, you can try the add-on [LaTeXify](http://www.winedt.org/config/menus/LaTeXify.html) which adds lots of buttons for this type of automated compilation.

---

At last, but not least, the add-on [arara](http://www.winedt.org/config/menus/arara.html) lets you launch the famous tool `arara` from within WinEdt, if you would like to opt for this (which is probably the best tool for dealing with such automated compilations nowadays!!!).