# Create an accessory that executes latex->dvi2ps->ps2pdf in WinEdt

Tags: automation, winedt

I use `WinEdt` Build 20131031 (v. 8.1) 64-bit with Windows 7 and MikTeX 2.9.

I would like to create an accessory (`"latexdvi2ps2pdf"`) in execution modes for compiling tex documents in the following order:

```
LaTeX -> dvi2ps -> ps2pdf
```

Is this possible with `WinEdt`?

Comment: See Section "LaTeX + dvips + ps2pdf + View PDF" of karlkoeller's answer 
 and may be Possible Duplicate of [Quick Build commands in WinEdt](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119101/quick-build-commands-in-winedt)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update (2016-04-20)

The add-on [LaTeXify](http://www.winedt.org/config/menus/LaTeXify.html) now adds two commands "TeXify2PDF" (which runs BibTeX and TeXify+dvips+ps2pdf with LaTeX engine) and "LaTeXify2PDF" (which runs Biber and TeXify+dvips+ps2pdf with LaTeX engine) to accomplish your needs.

---

### Original answer

Follow these steps to have a menu entry, a keyboard shortcut and a toolbar button for an accessory that runs LaTeX -> dvips -> ps2pdf in WinEdt 8.

1. Show the "Options Interface" (Options -> Options Interface)

   [image]
2. Double-click the "Main Menu" item (`MainMenu.ini` gets opened)
3. Just before the line

   ```
     ITEM="Compile"
   ```

   add the following lines

   ```
     ITEM="dvi2ps2pdf"
       CAPTION="dvi2ps2pdf"
       IMAGE="TeXIconRed"
       SAVE_INPUT=1
       MACRO=`Assign("Old-PDFTeXify-Method","%$('PDFTeXify-Method');");`+
             `Assign("PDFTeXify-Method","2");`+
             `Exe('%b\Exec\TeX\PDFTeXify.edt');`+
             `Assign("PDFTeXify-Method","%$('Old-PDFTeXify-Method');");`+
             `Release("Old-PDFTeXify-Method");`
       SHORTCUT="24665::Shift+Ctrl+Y"
       REQ_FILTER=:"%!M=TeX"|"%!M=TeX:STY"|"%!M=TeX:AUX"
     ITEM="-"
   ```
4. Press <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+F9</kbd>
5. Now (in the "Options Interface") double-click the "Toolbar" item (`Toolbar.ini` gets opened)
6. Just before the line

   ```
       MENU="ConTeXt"
   ```

   add the following lines

   ```
       MENU="dvi2ps2pdf"
       MENU="-"
   ```
7. Press <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+F9</kbd>

---

Now you have a toolbar button in the drop-down button containing all the compilers

[image]

a menu item in the "TeX" menu

[image]

and a shortcut (<kbd>Shift+Ctrl+Y</kbd>) to run LaTeX -> dvips -> ps2pdf automatically.

Comment: @Hamstibamsti You're welcome. Happy to help and also happy that you accepted the answer. ;-)