# Adding a new command in Winedt 8

Tags: winedt

I would like to create a single command or rather a single button that executes the commands 
`latex`-`dvi-ps`-`ps-pdf` in a sequence. How do I customize Winedt 8 to achieve this?

### In general, my question is, how to add new customizations to the existing Winedt 8 System.

Comment: Does this help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119101/quick-build-commands-in-winedt

Comment: You need this: [Create an accessory that executes latex->dvi2ps->ps2pdf in WinEdt](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/162666)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is already explained [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/162666) by Karl Koeller. He uses `PDFTeXify` method for this. If you want a brute `LaTeX` + `DVIPS` + `PS2PDF`, follow the steps as explained in the linked answer. But instead of

```
  ITEM="dvi2ps2pdf"
    CAPTION="dvi2ps2pdf"
    IMAGE="TeXIconRed"
    SAVE_INPUT=1
    MACRO=`Assign("Old-PDFTeXify-Method","%$('PDFTeXify-Method');");`+
          `Assign("PDFTeXify-Method","2");`+
          `Exe('%b\Exec\TeX\PDFTeXify.edt');`+
          `Assign("PDFTeXify-Method","%$('Old-PDFTeXify-Method');");`+
          `Release("Old-PDFTeXify-Method");`
    SHORTCUT="24665::Shift+Ctrl+Y"
    REQ_FILTER=:"%!M=TeX"|"%!M=TeX:STY"|"%!M=TeX:AUX"
  ITEM="-"
```

use

```
  ITEM="dvi2ps2pdfSS"    // SS for your name ;)
    CAPTION="dvi2ps2pdfSS"
    IMAGE="TeXIconWood"
    SAVE_INPUT=1
    MACRO=`Exe('%b\Exec\TeX\LaTeX.edt');`+
          `Exe('%b\Exec\TeX\dvi2ps.edt');`+
          `Exe('%b\Exec\TeX\ps2pdf.edt');`
    SHORTCUT="24650::Shift+Ctrl+J"
    REQ_FILTER=:"%!M=TeX"|"%!M=TeX:STY"|"%!M=TeX:AUX"
 ITEM="-"
```

and in `Toolbar.ini`, use

```
MENU="dvi2ps2pdfSS"
```